# Spring Boot - trouble with Spring Security dependecies : UserDetailsService.class cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Until today my app worked perfectly but suddenly I got this exception and I don't know how can I fix it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.company.app.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]

.....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:177) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:99) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:703) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:886) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:373) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:321) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:190) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:293) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
... 43 common frames omitted
```

I commented the class implementing `UserDetailsService` but now I have this exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1269) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
... 80 common frames omitted
```

It seems like the Spring Security dependencies cause some trouble.

My pom.xml (summary):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My implementations (even if this is not the issue) :

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private SecurityService securityService;

   @Override
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername( String username ) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return new CustomUserDetails( securityService.findUserCredentialsByUsername( username ) );
  }
}
```

**Edit**

It seems strange because I can run my tests and all those tests load the context from the main class `Application`. Tests do not fail but when I run the application in Tomcat, it fails !

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your classpath is out of date because the **UserService.class** and **GrantedAuthority.class** files are not found. You can fix that by updating your maven dependencies and make sure dependencies are in the classpath.

Comment: I already update my dependencies and launched a `mvn clean install` but nothing changes

Comment: Maybe dependencies are not well downloaded. try to manualy remove them under  C:\users\yourAccount\.m2\org\springframework and do a fresh `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a corrupt jar file in you local maven repository. That can lead to errors because maven cannot access the class files in these jars.